# Beginner error in jquery use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After 3 years full of C/C++, I decide to return in the JS world.

But i'm stuck on a error that i don't understand. I'll try to make this little script but all i get is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when alert is fired.

```
$(function() {
    $('.smooth-gradient').click(function() {
        alert(this.height());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/am3jb7xa/

Comment: alert(this.height) - no parens, i think.

Comment: `alert($(this).height());` - `this` itself has no `height()` method - you need it in a jQuery object.

Comment: without the parens is plain old javascript, not jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It misses the `$()` around `this`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.smooth-gradient').click(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('.smooth-gradient').click(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
    });
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/am3jb7xa/5/)

Answer (score 1):

`this`: functions as a selector

```
$(this)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't function as a *selector*; jQuery allows DOM elements to be passed in to the `$( )` function.

Comment: is true. but is defined as a selector